# Adding a vertical line to an Area Chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

First time working with ASP.NET charting and any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm trying to add a vertical line to an area chart like the following...

[image]

```
<asp:Chart id="chtTriage" Width="545" BackColor="#f2f2f2" runat="server">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="srs" ChartType="Area" Color="LightGray">
                    <Points>
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="0" YValues="1000" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="5" YValues="2500" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="10" YValues="6000" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="15" YValues="4000" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="20" YValues="2500" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="25" YValues="2000" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="30" YValues="1500" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="35" YValues="1200" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="40" YValues="1000" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="45" YValues="500" />
                        <asp:DataPoint XValue="50" YValues="0" />
                    </Points>
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="chaTriage" BackColor="#f2f2f2">
                    <AxisY Title="Number of Dogs" Interval="1000" IntervalType="Number" IsMarginVisible="false">
                        <LabelStyle Font="Aerial, 8.25pt" />
                        <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX Title="Triage Points" Interval="10" IntervalType="Number" IsStartedFromZero="true" Minimum="0" IsMarginVisible="false">
                        <LabelStyle Font="Aerial, 8.25pt" />
                        <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Has anyone ever run across this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The way I managed to do it with a line graph is like this:

```
var dateLine = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
dateLine.AxisX = AttendGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
dateLine.AxisY = AttendGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
dateLine.LineColor = Color.DarkBlue;
dateLine.LineWidth = 2;
dateLine.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
dateLine.AnchorX = eventInfo.StartDate.AddDays(1).Date.ToOADate();
dateLine.AnchorY = 0;
dateLine.ClipToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
dateLine.IsInfinitive = true;           

AttendGraph.Annotations.Add(dateLine);
```

My x-axis is a date which I set with the anchorX.  AttendGraph is the chart control.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding another series of type column.

```
<asp:Series Name="line" ChartType="Column" Color="#D33729">
    <Points>
        <asp:DataPoint XValue="12" YValues="6000" />
     </Points>
</asp:Series>
```